# Activating and Deactivating PushBots from CheckboxPreference

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, checkboxpreference

I am using [PushBots](https://pushbots.com/) in my Android Application but would like to give the user an option to Enable or Disable the Notifications. On the [PushBots website](https://pushbots.com/developer/gcm#g6), it says that running the code `Pushbots.getInstance().setRegStatus(false);` will do this for me.

So, I have created a preference page and created a CheckboxPreference option and I would like it to deactivate notifications (run the code) when unticked and re-activate them (run the same code but with `true` instead of `false`) when ticked.

Here is my Preference page (Prefs.java):

```
import com.pushbots.push.Pushbots;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.CheckBoxPreference;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Prefs extends PreferenceActivity implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {
boolean CheckboxPreference;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {

   super.onDestroy();
   Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Preferences saved!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
}  
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        getPrefs();
    }
private void getPrefs() {
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    }
@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,
        final String key) {
    if (key.equals(notifBox)) {
        // handle setting enabled or disabled depending on value of preference
        if (sharedPreferences.getBoolean(key, false)) {
            Pushbots.getInstance().setRegStatus(true);
        } else {
            Pushbots.getInstance().setRegStatus(false);
        }   }   }   }
```

And my Preference layout (preferences.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<CheckBoxPreference
      android:title="Notifications"
      android:defaultValue="true"
      android:summary="Recieve push notifications from IGNITE?"
      android:key="notifBox"
      android:textIsSelectable="false" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

And my Main Activity runs the following two lines:

```
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext()).registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
      SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
```

The app remembers the preferences, even after closing and re-opening, however, no matter what the state of the option is, I get push notifications.

I have looked through many tutorials, questions on here and resources on the Android Developer website however none seem to either fit my need or work in my instance.

Any suggestions will be gratefully appreciated! :)